# Grails Groovy - Cannot access a static Map (collection) from another class

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a class to store all my constant values, and everything was fine until I decided to store a Map.

```
final class Constants {
    public static final Map states = [a: 1,b: 2]
}
```

And inside a service:

```
assert Constants.states.a == 1
```

Results in error:

```
assert Constants.states.a == 1 | | a false
```

It's returning the key instead of the value. And happends only if the Map is in another class, because if I declare it inside of the same class where I make the assert, everything works as expected.

I'm really confused, that is not supposed to happend, is it ?

Comment: I think you've got some typos in your example code up there.  I was going clean them up, but I can't tell what the correct code is.  Please edit the second (I think it's supposed to be `Constants.states.a`) and third code blocks (which was an assertion error, I assume).  Also, I don't have any trouble when I use your example Constants class.

Comment: I corrected the typos, sorry about that. The assertion error is copied directly from the error page that grails returns. And even the stack trace says that I'm trying to compare a == 1

Answer (score 0):

Is this class public when you add the final access specifier? Check that first. If it is then try 
assert Constants.states.get('a') == 1

Comment: Yes, the class is public, it has many more properties that I can access without any problem. And I have already tried .get('a') and ['a'] but the same happends

Comment: Are you sure you're doing `assert Constants.states.a == 1` and not `assert Constants.a == 1` like you question suggests

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, I mistyped my question. I'm doing `Constants.states.a == 1`. (I corrected it).